# ASP.NET MVC Get the ID of Inserted Item by ExecuteSqlCommand

Tags: database, ado.net

I do insertion with following in my ASP.NET MVC3 project:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(//some values)";
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
```

Is there an easy way to get the inserted row's ID?

**EDIT:**

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addGetID
( 
    @PersonnelID INT,
    @ShiftWorkID BIGINT,
    @EntranceDateTime DATETIME,
    @WorkflowStateRelationID BIGINT
)
AS
INSERT INTO DynamicDataEntrances VALUES (@PersonnelID, @ShiftWorkID, @EntranceDateTime, @WorkflowStateRelationID)
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

My code lines:

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
SqlParameter PersonnelID = new SqlParameter("@PersonnelID", 1);
SqlParameter ShiftWorkID = new SqlParameter("@ShiftWorkID", 2);
SqlParameter EntranceDateTime = new SqlParameter("@EntranceDateTime", dt);
SqlParameter WorkflowStateRelationID = new SqlParameter("@WorkflowStateRelationID ", db.WorkflowStateRelations.Where(wsr => wsr.WorkflowID == dp.WorkflowID).Select(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault());
SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter();
returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

// try 1
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("addGetID(@PersonnelID, @ShiftWorkID, @EntranceDateTime, @WorkflowStateRelationID )", PersonnelID, ShiftWorkID, EntranceDateTime, WorkflowStateRelationID, returnValue);

// try 2
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("addGetID @PersonnelID @ShiftWorkID @EntranceDateTime @WorkflowStateRelationID ", PersonnelID, ShiftWorkID, EntranceDateTime, WorkflowStateRelationID, returnValue);

// try 3
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec addGetID @PersonnelID={0} @ShiftWorkID={1} @EntranceDateTime={2} @WorkflowStateRelationID={3} ", PersonnelID, ShiftWorkID, EntranceDateTime, WorkflowStateRelationID, returnValue);

var id = returnValue.Value;
```

Comment: You can use your savechance ef the value of the id at the end of the command.

Comment: And I asked how to do that :)

Comment: ooo İsmet :) kardeşim bir orm kullansana yahu, t-sql ile ne kasıp suruyorsun. Bu şekilde sadece ters sıralayıp top(1) yapabilirsin.

Comment: Saçma sapan bir projenin içinde saçma sapan relationlardan kurtulamayıp ExecuteSqlCommand kullanmak zorunda kalınca @İsmetAlkan ile aynı duruma düşmek mümkün.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with [scartag][1] on this one.  But to answer your question in 2 parts.

If you're going to use direct sql then the thing to do is create a stored proc that returns the `@@IDENTITY` value.  Then you exec your Sp with a parameter of `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` and use that value.

Like such:

```
SqlParameter entityField = new SqlParameter("@firstName", "Frank");
SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter();
returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_ByPassEFAndInsertEntity(@firstName)", 
                              entityField, returnValue);
var id = returnValue.Value;
```

Or just use EF.  Create and initialize your `Entity`, add it to the applicable `DbSet` and call savechanges.  Your Entity instance's Id column will be updated with the value generated by the database.

EDIT 2:  I applied the first solution to a local db of mine and could get it to give a return value either.  After some research I was able to get a return value.  I have a local db with a Blog table.  I created an addBlog SP and this is how you can get a return value - but instead of using ExecSqlCommand you must use SqlQuery.

Here's my SP:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addBlog] 
        @BlogName varchar(50),
        @CreateDateTime datetime
    AS
    BEGIN
        insert into Blog (Name, DateTimeCreated) values (@BlogName, @CreateDateTime)
        declare @return int
        set @return = @@identity
        select @return
    END
```

and my EF code:

```
    using (var db = new StackOverflowEntities()) {
        SqlParameter blogName = new SqlParameter("BlogName", "New Name 2");
        SqlParameter createDate = new SqlParameter("CreateDate", DateTime.Now);

        int? newIdentityValue = db.Database.SqlQuery<Int32>("addBlog @BlogName, @CreateDate", blogName, createDate).FirstOrDefault();

        Debug.WriteLine(newIdentityValue);
    }
```

Comment: I created the stored procedure. But I can't get it working for multiple entity fields, can you edit your question as working for multiple entity fields. I don't need to add references to objects (I mean mapping) by changing properties, do I?

Comment: Edited according to request.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Hope that sorts it out

Comment: The whitespaces weren't present on my actual code, just pasting here fault, sorry about that. I get the dateTime values from dateTimePickers in the project, so dateTime isn't a problem here. And as I said, I already tried this. For your effort I tried your exact lines of code. But it returns "Incorrect syntax near '@PersonnelID'."

Comment: @Ismet - you're right, it doesn't work.  I applied it to a local db i had.  I did some research and found out how to achieve it through EF, tested it against my local db.  See my edit if you're still looking for an answer.  This time i tested it...! :\

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot get the inserted row's ID from this method.

It only returns an int (which tells you the number of rows affected).

Your code tells me you are already using EF so why not use other aspects of the API?

Since you seem keen on going the raw sql route, why not use a tool like dapper, massive or petapoco?

Comment: I don't get a ready Model from the post, I do some modifications and do inserting accordingly. Can you tell me a way that I can get the ID I want that is applicable with code based attributes?

Comment: Did your question just change or am I losing it? ;)

Comment: You know you stated what I want in your answer :)

Comment: I said that to @Quinton Bernhardt :)

Comment: What I meant is, he answered in a way that I want, but I haven't got a solution depending on his recommendation. I hope I stated myself clearly.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT scope_identity()
```

as your returned value