# Executing Sql Server Stored Procedure and getting OUTPUT INSERTED value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to get inserted row key when inserting records.Then I wrote this Sample SQL SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  Temp
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
insert  into Farmer_landDetails 
(oth_mas_key,
fmr_key,
anim_typ_key,
anim_count,
land_type_key,
land_availability) OUTPUT INSERTED.oth_det_key values(1,1,1,1,1,1) 
END
GO
```

How to get this `OUT` value with C# ?

Comment: Why don't you simply select the row inserted after insertion? Do you have a primary key among the columns?

Comment: Execute this from C# using ExecuteScalar

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182684/asp-net-mvc-get-the-id-of-inserted-item-by-executesqlcommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Output clause of your StoredProcedure returns a single row with a single value.
So the correct method to get its result is through the ExecuteScalar method of an SqlCommand

```
using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Temp", cnn))
{
   cnn.Open();
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Notice that I have no idea what datatype is `oth_det_key`. I assume an integer hence the Convert.ToInt32() on the return value of ExecuteScalar